# Button padding setting not working

Tags: asp.net, css

I have set button paddings in stylesheet, this works on my XP machine. But when I moved  it to a 2003 server, the padding between Text and the border of the button is really big.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                <tr class="TableHeader">
                    <td>
                        Computer Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        First Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Last Name
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" style="padding-left: 20px">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search for approved computers" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComp" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

CSS file:

```
.TableHeader
{
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #006400; 
    text-align: center;
}
.ButtonPadding
{
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

I used the IE 8 developer tool to check the button setting and it looks fine, but the actual display is not.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have this line in skin file: <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="ButtonPadding" />

Comment: OK. I think I figured it out, actually googled it out. For anyone who is suffering the same issue, the problem is the "Compatibility View" setting of IE. As soon as I turned that off, everything displays just as expected.

Comment: Further search found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197   Now I can set this in IIS, no need to worry about changing group policy.

Answer (score 0):

I see `.ButtonPadding` in the stylesheet, but it doesn't appear anywhere in the HTML code you've supplied, so it's not a suprise that it's not working.

You need to specify `class='ButtonPadding'` on the elements that you want it to apply to.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to see what css you have set to your button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search for approved computers" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

CssClass= "ButtonPadding" is missing
```

Alternatively if you don't want to specify css that will apply to automatically, then your css should be look like...

```
  input[type=text], input[type=password]  {

padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I have this line in skin file: <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="ButtonPadding" />.  As I mentioned above, the button padding looks fine on my XP machine. It's just not working when I moved to a server.

Comment: okay, so you can confirm that the if you view source on the generated HTML code, it has `class='ButtonPadding'` in the button?

Comment: Yes. the html looks like: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch" value="Search for approved computers" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch" class="ButtonPadding" />

Comment: did you add css file in your master page ?

Comment: css file is under my App_Theme folder and theme is specified in web.config.

Comment: I just tried your alternative suggestion with [type=submit] above and it didn't change anything.

Comment: its OK that it is under App_Theme folder, but did you add reference in your page <link href="../App_Themes/Standard/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: I tried your suggestion to add the <link> into master page, it didn't work.

Comment: I just cannot figure out why it displays differently on two machines.

Comment: can you clear your browser cache ? it may sometiems be the problem

Comment: Ok. I cannot delete all cache because our stupid policy. But I tried another computer, it still looked the same. I also tried firefox and the button looks perfect in firefox.

Comment: maybe its browser issue, you can check in different version

Comment: If it is just a browser issue, why does IE 8 displays button fine when I host the website on my XP machine? Sometimes these issues really drive me crazy because I cannot figure out where even to start to look for problems.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I figured it out, actually googled it out. For anyone who is suffering the same issue, the problem is the "Compatibility View" setting of IE. As soon as I turned that off, everything displays just as expected.

Further search found this: support.microsoft.com/kb/956197 Now I can set this in IIS, no need to worry about changing group policy